# Access 365 - No duplicates based on a forgein key

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, office365, ms-office

I have an issue/problem that I'm looking for a solution for. If I find a solution for this, it could fix two issues I'm facing in a database tool I'm creating for my school's admin office.

The gist of it is, I'm looking for a way in Access 365 (or Access 2019) either through a form/query/vba... to limit data to not have duplicates. Now, of course I know that you can set the field in your table to not have duplicates. But, here is the thing, I wouldn't mind a duplicate in that column in certain cases.

So, let me explain the issue/problem by giving an example.

Image that you have two tables. One table is filled with the name of a school bus and the yearly price that the parents have to pay for it. Another table has all the stops that the school busses take.

Now, here comes the problem. I would love to have a system where I can let the user decide the order of those stops.

What I'm currently doing is, I let the user fill in a number. In another column, I have a calculated field that adds the primary key of the schoolbus table "." the number of the order.

So, that would look like this for the first school bus and the first five stops.

1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5

And I have a duplicate control that column. Since that way, I can make sure that it doesn't block the number 1 for the next bus.

Something that might work as well, if that's possible in access is that for each school bus you create, you add a column in the stops table to check for duplicates. But how do you make sure then to filter which stops belongs to which schoolbus?

I hope my issue is a bit clear. If it's not, feel free to ask.

I have a similar style problem in another part of the tool with a book fair system.

Where you have an order table where the order number, the student number, the creation and pickup dates are stored. It also has a field to lock the form to avoid any edits for the bookkeeping folks. I also have an orderline form where all the actual bought books are stored. Now, I would love it if a system exists to avoid users adding the same book twice on an order in the orderline table since I do have an amount column for that. So, in a way, it's almost similar to the above described problem.

Comment: 2 column unique index on bus #, stop id ?

Comment: That's what I'm sort of doing no...? I create a calculated field based upon busnumber and stop id... But Access doesn't allow duplicate checking on a calculated field... :/ So, I copy that over to a text column where I do have "No Duplicates" check. But, is that a bit overkill...?

Comment: Index not calculated field.  All unique restrictions rely on an index, especially a primary key!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+access+create+unique+index+two+columns

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett Thanks man, I got it working. It was so confusing that I didn't need to give the second column an index name. :o That was my problem. My OCD was screwing with me. Thanks for the help and advice man!

Comment: Good programmers balance OCD with laziness!  :D